# How to install iOS app release build on Simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator

I've build an iOS app based on Xamarin, which is already available in the App Store. Now I made a new version with new functionality and when I tested it before uploading to the App Store. Everything works fine. But the App Store team rejects it due to a crash after signing in in the app.

I tested next situations:

1. Debug build on simulator
2. Debug build on real device
3. Release build on real device (using Testflight)

Every situation works for me. The only thing I haven't tested is a release build on a simulator, because I don't know how to install that such build on a simulator. How can I do that?

Comment: 1 For release you need a production certificate and production ad-hoc profile. 2 I'm not sure you can install a release build on simulator at all, use real device.

Answer (score 0):

You can not install a release build to the simulator. And I am pretty much sure Apple reviewers are not testing your application on a simulator too.

I would suggest you create a test flight ([here is how to use testflight](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10868372-testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing)) beta and Install the test flight builds on your phone. If it seems like a device-dependent issue which the Review team would have mentioned, invite a friend with the same device as an internal tester.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the solution is not to test a relesae build on a simulator. I already tested the app with Testflight and the same device and iOS-version, which didn't crash for me... Too bad, I will go back (again) to the iOS team to discuss about this. I need to find out what te problem is, and therefor I first want to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Although in my experience they come with steps to reproduce the error, if not you can always ask for that on the resolution center. Plus attach the screenshot of working steps in case you don't find a crash on the same build shared for review.

Comment: `You can not install a release build to the simulator.` I just created a fresh Xcode project (iOS app) and installed it using release mode on my simulator.